# How to play video in emacs?

Tags: emacs, video-playback

I use emacs as my primary editor. I'd really like to not have to leave it at all during my workday, but I do more than just code on my computer.

Is there a way to play video in emacs?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emms/

Comment: In spacemacs, emacs25.1, the emms said don't know how to track file